latex \pstTriangle problem
I try to create a macro to draw a Thales' configuration :
\newcommand{\ThalesLenzen}[9]{
    % Tracé du grand triangle
    \pstTriangle[linewidth=1pt,PointSymbol=none,PointNameSep=3mm](#1){#2}(#3){#4}(#5){#6}
    % Construction des points images fictifs par homothétie
    \pstHomO[HomCoef=#9,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{#1}{#4,#6}[x,y]
    % Tracé du petit triangle
    \pstTriangle[linewidth=1pt,PointSymbol=none,PointNameSep=3mm,PointNameA=none](#1){#2}(x){#7}(y){#8}
}

When I compile this :
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(16.5,5) \grille
    \uput[r](0,4){a)}       \rput(1,3){\ThalesLenzen{0,0}{A}{3,0}{B}{2,2}{C}{E}{D}{.7}}
    \uput[r](6,4){b)}       \rput(7,4.7){\ThalesLenzen{0,0}{P}{4,-1}{S}{1,-2}{N}{E}{I}{.4}}
\end{pspicture}

I get this output :


Position of points D and E are not correct. What is the problem ?
Have you a better idea to place points name (for example "D" should be perpendicular to [AC] and E perpendicular to [PS]) ??

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit : solution found !
With this macro
\newcommand{\ThalesLenzen}[9]{
    % Tracé du grand triangle
    \pstTriangle[linewidth=1pt,PointSymbol=none,PointNameSep=3mm](#1){#2}(#3){#4}(#5){#6}
    % Construction des points images fictifs par homothétie
    \pstHomO[HomCoef=#9,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{#1}{#4,#6}[x,y]
    % Placement des points "parallèles" et tracé du segment
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=90,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{x}{#2}[x']    
    \pstProjection[PointSymbol=none,PointNameSep=3mm]{#2}{#4}{x'}[#7]
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-90,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{y}{#2}[y']   
    \pstProjection[PointSymbol=none,PointNameSep=3mm]{#2}{#6}{y'}[#8]
    \pstLineAB{#7}{#8}
}

I got this result, and it's fine for me :

